# How can I make the cardview's disappear?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-cardview

When I click on any menu item present in the navigation drawer, the content of the menu item appears below the cards. The cards should disappear and then in their place the content of the menu items should be displayed. The contents of the menu items are written in the form of fragments. Could someone help me out in solving it? Attaching the code below...

Here is the MainActivity Java file

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.menu_profile:
                    fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new ProfileFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Profile");
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                case R.id.menu_language:
                    fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new LanguageFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Set Language");
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                case R.id.menu_tutorial:
                    fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new TutorialFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Tutorial");
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    >
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         android:id="@+id/main_container">
        <include
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
            />
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_fixed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/background_light">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/card_fixed_heading"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Sensor Details"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/card_fixed_details"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="pH Level - \nTemperature - \nMoisture -"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_notification"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/background_light">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/card_notification_heading"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Water The Plants!"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Done"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_prediction"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/background_light">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/card_market_heading"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Market Prediction"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Click Here!"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:onClick="marketPrediction"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_pest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/background_light">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/card_pest_heading"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Pest Details"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Click Here!"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:onClick="pestDetails"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
     </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
        >
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to fetch ID of the `CardView` and store it in a variable.

   CardView cardView = findViewById(R.id.card_fixed);
2. After doing that, you need to `setVisibility` to `GONE` to hide the `CardView`'s wherever you want to.

   cardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
3. Whenever you `setVisibility` to your `View`, there are three options,

`View.VISIBLE`, `View.INVISIBLE`, `View.GONE`.

4. You can `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to make the `CardView`'s or any other `Views` appear back.
5. `View.INVISIBLE` takes up space for layout purposes, but `View.GONE` won't take any space.

**(For some reason I'm unable to format the code to make `CardView` visibility to `GONE`.)**

Answer (score 0):

Every `Android View` has an ability to appear and disappear. Just use the `setVisibility()` in your java code and set it to `View.GONE`

Example:

```
CardView cardView1 = findViewById(R.id.card_pest);

cardView1.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val cardView = findViewById<CardView>(R.id.cardview2)
val destroyer = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView8)
destroyer.setOnClickListener {
     cardView.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?